# Copy a DOCX table cell with styling and images to a new document

Tags: python, python-docx

I am having problems to copy a table cell from a DOCX file to a new, empty document with all relevant styles and images

The styling should include bullet points or numbered lists, too. Also, the autoformatted arrows (==> or -->) also seem to be missing entirely.

This is my starting point:

```
from docx import Document

def copy_cell_content(cell, outfile):
    """
    Copy formatted cell to DOCX outfile.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    * cell : docx.table._Cell
    * outfile : str output file path

    Returns
    -------
    None.
    """
    ## Create a new document for output
    output_doc = Document()

    ## Iterate over paragraphs of the cell
    for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:                
        ## Create a new paragraph
        new_paragraph = output_doc.add_paragraph()
        
        ## Copy paragraph alignment
        new_paragraph.alignment = paragraph.alignment

        ## Copy paragraph style
        # new_paragraph.style = paragraph.style
        
        ## Iterate over runs of the paragraph
        for run in paragraph.runs:            
            ## Copy text
            new_run = new_paragraph.add_run(run.text)

            # Copy font data
            new_run.style.name = run.style.name
            
            ## Copy formatting 
            new_run.bold = run.bold
            new_run.italic = run.italic
            new_run.underline = run.underline
            new_run.font.size = run.font.size
            new_run.font.name = run.font.name
            new_run.font.underline = run.font.underline
            new_run.font.subscript = run.font.subscript
            new_run.font.superscript = run.font.superscript
            new_run.font.color.rgb = run.font.color.rgb 
            new_run.font.small_caps = run.font.small_caps

            ## TODO: copy list styles
            ## TODO: copy inline images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have not fully achieved what I hoped for, but I have made some progress. Best results are achieved with a "raw" copy of entire paragraphs. Images are still not copied, though, only a broken placeholder. Styling is incomplete, but good enough.

This raw copying works fine when the target is a document. However, when a table cell is copied to a new table, this result in a broken document. For this, I must resort to a "by run" approach, which is less complete.

```
def _copy_cell_raw(source_cell, target, skiplines=0, debug=False):
    """
    Copy cell content with formatting to a target cell or paragraph.

    --> https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/182
    --> https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/156
    --> https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/270
    --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713465/python-docx-copy-table
    --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965042/python-docx-insertion-point

    Parameters
    ----------
    * source_cell : docx.table._Cell
    * target : docx.table._Cell *or* docx.document.Document
    * skiplines : int initial paragraphs to skip

    Returns
    -------
    None.
    """
    ## TODO: Fix indendation level formatting of bullet points and numbered lists
    ## TODO: Fix raw table copying
    ## TODO: Fix broken images

    ## Iterate over paragraphs of the cell
    for i, paragraph in enumerate(source_cell.paragraphs[skiplines:]):
        if debug:
            print(f'>> {i:3d}/{len(source_cell.paragraphs)} : {paragraph.style.name}/{paragraph.alignment}')

        ## Copy paragraph from source to target (cell or document)
        ## TODO: remove leading newline
        if type(target) is docx.document.Document:
            new_paragraph = target._body._body._insert_p(paragraph._p)
        else:
            new_paragraph = target._element._insert_p(paragraph._p)

        if paragraph._p.get_or_add_pPr().numPr is not None:
            new_paragraph.style = paragraph.style.name

    ## Iterate over tables of the cell
    for i, table in enumerate(source_cell.tables):
        if debug:
            print(f'\n>> {i:3d} : {table}')

        ## 1) Copy table low-level
        ## TODO: results in corrupted data when the table is embedded in a table
        # new_table = copy.deepcopy(table._tbl)
        # new_paragraph = target.add_paragraph()
        # new_paragraph._p.addnext(new_table)
        ## 2) Copy table by runs
        ## Get the table layout
        rows, cols = 0, 0
        for row in table.rows:
            rows += 1
        for col in table.rows[0].cells:
            cols += 1
        ## Create a new paragraph in the target (cell or document)
        new_table = target.add_table(rows, cols)
        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range(cols):
                source_cell = table.cell(row, col)
                target_cell = new_table.cell(row, col)
                _copy_cell_byruns(source_cell, target_cell)
    if debug:
        print("<< Cell copied!\n")


def _copy_cell_byruns(source_cell, target, skiplines=0, debug=False):
    """
    Copy cell content with formatting to a target cell or paragraph.

    --> https://groups.google.com/g/python-docx/c/yEuOJRB1dpY

    Parameters
    ----------
    * source_cell : docx.table._Cell
    * target : docx.table._Cell *or* docx.document.Document
    * skiplines : int initial paragraphs to skip

    Returns
    -------
    None.
    """
    ## TODO: Handle list styles
    ## TODO: Handle images

    ## Iterate over paragraphs of the cell
    for i, paragraph in enumerate(source_cell.paragraphs[skiplines:]):
        if debug:
            print(f'\n>> {i:3d} : {paragraph.style.name}/{paragraph.alignment}')

        ## Create a new paragraph in the target (cell or document)
        if i == 0 and type(target) is docx.table._Cell:
            new_paragraph = target.paragraphs[-1]
        else:
            new_paragraph = target.add_paragraph()

        ## Iterate over runs of the source paragraph
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            ## Copy text
            new_run = new_paragraph.add_run(run.text)

            ## Copy character and font styles
            new_run.bold = run.bold
            new_run.italic = run.italic
            new_run.underline = run.underline
            new_run.font.size = run.font.size
            new_run.font.name = run.font.name
            new_run.font.underline = run.font.underline
            new_run.font.subscript = run.font.subscript
            new_run.font.superscript = run.font.superscript
            new_run.font.color.rgb = run.font.color.rgb
            new_run.font.small_caps = run.font.small_caps
            try:
                new_run.style = run.style.name
            except KeyError:
                pass

            if debug:
                print(f' > {i:3d} : {run.style.name}')
                print(f' <       {new_run.style.name}')

        ## Copy paragraph alignment & style
        new_paragraph.alignment = paragraph.alignment
        try:
            new_paragraph.style = paragraph.style.name
        except KeyError:
            pass
        if debug:
            print(f'<<       {new_paragraph.style.name}/{new_paragraph.alignment}')

    ## Iterate over tables of the cell
    for i, table in enumerate(source_cell.tables):
        if debug:
            print(f'\n>> {i:3d} : {table}')

        ## Get the table layout
        rows, cols = 0, 0
        for row in table.rows:
            rows += 1
        for col in table.rows[0].cells:
            cols += 1
        ## Create a new paragraph in the target (cell or document)
        new_table = target.add_table(rows, cols)
        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range(cols):
                source_cell = table.cell(row, col)
                target_cell = new_table.cell(row, col)
                _copy_cell_byruns(source_cell, target_cell)
    if debug:
        print("<< Cell copied!\n")
```